# How can I get all user created databases in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want list of user created databases in sql server 2005. How can list all user created databases by T-SQL?

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is a 'better' way, but this works:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
where owner_sid != 1
```

Comment: This will show all databases where the owner is not the 'sa' login.  So, if you have user databases where the owner is 'sa', then they will also be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

You query sys.databases and remove the system ones. True system databases are `master`, `tempdb`, `model` (ie. db_id 1, ,2 and 3) and `mssqlsystemresource`. However `mssqlsystemresource` has some magic behind and does not appear to exists. On the other hand everybody but the SQL engine considers `msdb` to be a system database too. So the query will be something like:

```
select * from sys.databases 
where name not in (N'master', N'tempdb', N'model', N'msdb')
```

Comment: btw there are also other 'ambiguos' databases, like the replicaiton distribution database, ReportServer and ResportServerTempDB.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
exec sp_databases
```

however that will include the system databases, so you'd need to manually exclude them. Not sure if there's a different system sproc that will do it for you.

While you can get more extended info using

```
select * from sys.databases
```

I'm quite sure the owner_sid field isn't a reliable indicator of a system database, since I have the same sid on both system and some user databases on my server here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, owner_sid
FROM sys.databases
```

owner_sid should provide enough info to distinguish, although I noticed that my [Oslo_Repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd129569(VS.85).aspx) sid was also specified as 1, so it might not be 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [name]
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE dbid > 6
```